# Use IF/CASE statement to find if a substring exist in a string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a column which has a list of products in each row. e.g:

- bat,ball,gloves
- bat,gloves
- shoes,gloves

I want to make a new column for each of the product, which will have a value of 1 or 0 depending on if that product exists in that row.

I'm using the following code right now:

```
select
*,
CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%bat%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS bat,
CASE WHEN product_name LIKE '%gloves%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS gloves
from products
```

It does not work. Kindly help

Comment: you should read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can use [handy MysQL function `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to check if a value belongs to a comma-separated list:

```
select
    p.*,
    find_in_set('bat', product_name) > 0 bat
    find_in_set('gloves', product_name) > 0 gloves
from products p
```

If the value is found in the CSV list, `find_in_set()` returns a number between 1 and N that represents its position; else it returns `0` (or `null` if the searched CSV list is `null`). So basically, to check if a value belong to the CSV list, you just need to check if the value returned by `find_in_set()` is strictly above `0`.

Comment: Thanks. the function works but it always returns 0. I don't know why. My products are not seperated by commas (e.g: batglovesball). so I'm quering find_in_set('bat',product_name). I also tried '%bat%' but it does not work